# Using apt-get from Canada

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates

I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, and until yesterday, everything was quite peachy. I have installed several packages (MySQL, apache2) and to my knowledge have those configured correctly. Upon configuration of phpMyAdmin, I found that I was missing the directory path /etc/phpmyadmin, which got me thinking about the install. I am new to Ubuntu, so I guess I missed the message telling me that I did not download phpMyAdmin successfully.

Anyway, trying to use apt-get yesterday/today results in "Failed to fetch..." messages, even if just to run sudo apt-get update.

Some notable details:
···no GUI, command line only (sudo apt-get gksu fails, go figure)
···can ping 4.2.2.2, so I know the internet is out there (somewhere)
···this is a dedicated computer, using Samba to share files with Windows, which does work
···attempted to edit my /sources.list file, for various American/Canadian mirror, to no effect
···ensured I have correct DNS settings in /etc/networks/interfaces

I'm not sure where along the way it happened, but I seem to have lost connections to repositories...  :)
Any advice (including GO BACK TO WINDOWS) is appreciated.

Edit: fixed by adding an actual nameserver to /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 2):

The actual solution to this problem was discovered by the original poster (and did not involve editing any of APT's configuration files). `resolv.conf` was blank. Adding a name server to it enabled `apt-get` to work. As the OP said:

> my /etc/resolv.conf was blank, had no nameservers what-so-ever. added
>   'nameserver 8.8.8.8' and presto! apt-get is my friend again!

Sources: See [this revision to the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/223925/2). The quote above is from [this old (now deleted) comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223925/using-apt-get-from-canada/223931#comment276350_223931).

Answer (score 0):

Please try following the instructions here to manage repositories using the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter) - it's safer than editing those files by hand:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Repositories_in_Ubuntu

Specifically, try the section about choosing a regional download server starting here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Download_Server

From that page:  Selecting "Other" provides the opportunity to select a participating server anywhere in the world.   Expand any of the country listings in the left pane and highlight a server. Then select "Choose Server" and pick one from Canada.

[edited to link to the software center page rather than using the technical word "GUI"]